# Python Requests encoding POST data

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

Version: Python 2.7.3

Other libraries: Python-Requests 1.2.3, jinja2 (2.6)

I have a script that submits data to a forum and the problem is that non-ascii characters appear as garbage. For instance a name like André Téchiné comes out as AndrÃ© TÃ©chinÃ©.

Here's how the data is submitted:

1) Data is initially loaded from a UTF-8 encoded CSV file like so:

```
entries = []
with codecs.open(filename, 'r', 'utf-8') as f:
    for row in unicode_csv_reader(f.readlines()[1:]):
        entries.append(dict(zip(csv_header, row)))
```

unicode_csv_reader is from the bottom of Python CSV documentation page: http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

When I type the entries name in the interpreter, I see the name as `u'Andr\xe9 T\xe9chin\xe9'`.

2) Next I render the data through jinja2:

```
tpl = tpl_env.get_template(u'forumpost.html')
rendered = tpl.render(entries=entries)
```

When I type the name rendered in the interpreter I see again the same: `u'Andr\xe9 T\xe9chin\xe9'`

Now, if I write the rendered variable to a filename like this, it displays correctly:

```
with codecs.open('out.txt', 'a', 'utf-8') as f:
    f.write(rendered)
```

But I must send it to the forum:

3) In the POST request code I have:

```
params = {u'post': rendered}
headers = {u'content-type': u'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
session.post(posturl, data=params, headers=headers, cookies=session.cookies)
```

session is a Requests session.

And the name is displayed broken in the forum post. I have tried the following:

- Leave out headers
- Encode rendered as rendered.encode('utf-8') (same result)
- rendered = urllib.quote_plus(rendered) (comes out as all %XY)

If I type rendered.encode('utf-8') I see the following:

```
'Andr\xc3\xa9 T\xc3\xa9chin\xc3\xa9'
```

How could I fix the issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Your client behaves as it should e.g. running `nc -l 8888` as a server and making a request:

```
import requests

requests.post('http://localhost:8888', data={u'post': u'Andr\xe9 T\xe9chin\xe9'})
```

shows:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8888
Content-Length: 33
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, compress
Accept: */*
User-Agent: python-requests/1.2.3 CPython/2.7.3

post=Andr%C3%A9+T%C3%A9chin%C3%A9
```

You can check that it is correct:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.unquote_plus(b"Andr%C3%A9+T%C3%A9chin%C3%A9").decode('utf-8')
u'Andr\xe9 T\xe9chin\xe9'
```

- check the server decodes the request correctly. You could try to specify the charset:

  ```
  headers = {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"}
  ```

  the body contains only ascii characters so it shouldn't hurt and the correct server would ignore any parameters for `x-www-form-urlencoded` type anyway. Look for gory details in [URL-encoded form data](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#url-encoded-form-data)
- check the issue is not a display artefact i.e., the value is correct but it displays incorrectly

Comment: "check the issue is not a display artefact i.e., the value is correct but it displays incorrectly" - Thank you. That's the problem! Unfortunately it's a public forum and I can't change the default encoding. It responds with iso-8859-1 encoding. Can I use rendered.encode('iso-8859-1') or will that break things? Thanks.

Comment: try to set charset in the headers

Comment: Sending it as rendered.encode('iso-8859-1') seemed to work so I'll use that. I marked your answer as correct as it pointed to the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: To anyone else who finds this, you can use `urllib.parse.quote_from_bytes` and `urllib.parse.unquote_to_bytes` to send a bytes-type over a network without worrying as much about encoding.

Comment: @MicahSmith: the question has [tag:python-2.7] tag. There is no `urllib.parse` there. Anyway, the input is Unicode (as it should -- use Unicode to represent text inside your programs). Side-note: `unquote_plus()` is used here to convience OP that `requests.post()` works correctly -- you do not use it in your actual code.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Yes, sorry about that, my comment is off topic. Please ignore it if you have the same problem and system as asker. I left it because this answer was the only clue I could find about ensuring bytes-type data could be properly decoded on the receiving end.

Answer (score 2):

Try to decode into utf8:

```
unicode(my_string_variable, "utf8")
```

or decode and encode:

```
sometext = gettextfromsomewhere().decode('utf-8')
env = jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.PackageLoader('jinjaapplication', 'templates'))
template = env.get_template('mypage.html')
print template.render( sometext = sometext ).encode('utf-8')
```