# UTF-8 chars in WTForms Flask

Tags: python, utf-8, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I am pretty new at Flask so I hope this is not silly question. I use flask wtforms to send data to local database (MySQL). I need to use UTF-8 signs like (č, ć, đ, š etc.). I also tried changing encoding in the database but it didn't work. Do you have some recommandation for me, I would be grateful, thanks! :)

```
class RegistrationForm(Form):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=25)])
    lozinka = StringField('Lozinka', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=5, max=25)])
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=25)])
    ime = StringField('Ime', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=25)])
    prezime = StringField('Prezime', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=25)])
    tracking = StringField('Tracking', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=1000)])
```

and

```
@app.route('/register/', methods=["GET","POST"])
def register_page():
    form = RegistrationForm(request.form)
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = form.username.data
        lozinka = sha256_crypt.encrypt(str(form.lozinka.data))
        email = form.email.data
        ime = form.ime.data
        prezime = form.prezime.data
        tracking = form.tracking.data

        c, conn = connection()
        c.execute("INSERT INTO ucenici VALUES (NULL, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",(escape_string(username), escape_string(lozinka), escape_string(email), escape_string(ime), escape_string(prezime), escape_string(tracking)))

        c.execute("SELECT * FROM ucenici")
        data = c.fetchall()
        print(data)
        conn.commit()
        c.close()
        conn.close()
        return "unio sam"

    return render_template("register.html", form=form)
```

register.html file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>U NOS, U BAZU</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class = "container">
    <h4>Register</h4>
    <br>
    {% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
    <form method=post action="/register/">
        <dl>
            {{render_field(form.username)}}
            {{render_field(form.lozinka)}}
            {{render_field(form.email)}}
            {{render_field(form.ime)}}
            {{render_field(form.prezime)}}
            {{render_field(form.tracking)}}

        </dl>
        <p><input type=submit value=Register></p>
    </form>

    {% if error %}
    <p class="error"><strong>Error:</strong>{{error}}</p>
    {% endif %}

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is the problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: sorry if I was not clear

I would like to have data in base like "Paško" instead of "PaÅ¡ko"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Requests encoding POST data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417620/python-requests-encoding-post-data)

Answer (score 0):

Possible Duplicate of [Python Requests encoding POST data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417620/python-requests-encoding-post-data)

Try setting the charset in header par of request