# What is python requests packages equivalent to curl --data-urlencode call?

Tags: jenkins, python-requests

I am using the following command-line call to execute a groovy script on the jenkins CLI server:

```sh
curl --user 'Knitschi:myPassword' -H "Jenkins-Crumb:1234" --data-urlencode "script=println 'Hello nice jenkins-curl-groovy world!'" localhost:8080/scriptText
```

I am currently working on transforming my bash scripts to python and I want to do the equivalent of the above call with the python **requests** package (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/).

So-far I have

```py
import requests

url = 'http://localhost:8080/scriptText'
myAuth = ('Knitschi', 'myPassword')
crumbHeader = { 'Jenkins-Crumb' : '1234'}
scriptData = "script=println 'Hello cruel jenkins-python-groovy world!'"

response = requests.post(url, auth=myAuth, headers=crumbHeader, data=scriptData)
print(response.text)
response.raise_for_status()
```

While the command line prints the expected string, the python code does not.
It also does not raise an exception.

Also I am not sure if I should use `requests.get()` or `requests.post()`. My web-tech knowledge is very limited.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Requests encoding POST data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417620/python-requests-encoding-post-data)

Answer (score 2):

Using

```py
import requests

url = 'http://localhost:8080/scriptText'
myAuth = ('Knitschi', 'myPassword')
crumbHeader = { 'Jenkins-Crumb' : '1234'}
groovyScript = "println 'Hello cruel jenkins-python-groovy world!'"
scriptData = { "script" : groovyScript}

response = requests.post(url, auth=myAuth, headers=crumbHeader, data=scriptData)
print(response.text)
response.raise_for_status()
```

works at least for the groovy script in this example and the one that I use in reality. However the **urlencode** functionality seems to be missing here, so I am not sure if this works for all given groovy scripts.

Answer (score 1):

When passing a string in the `data` parameter, `requests` posts it without encoding it.

You can either use [`quote_plus`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote_plus) to encode your post data,

```
scriptData = "script=println 'Hello cruel jenkins-python-groovy world!'"
scriptData = urllib.parse.quote_plus(scriptData, '=')
```

or split by '&' and '=' to create a dictionary.

```
scriptData = "script=println 'Hello cruel jenkins-python-groovy world!'"
scriptData = dict(i.split('=') for i in scriptData.split('&'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It did not work directly, but it gave me clues that helped me to get to something that at least for my actual groovy-script works. Your first solution did not work. I get groovy syntax errors when using this, what makes me think that something with the encoding-decoding is not right.

Comment: Your second solution works for the simple hello-world scritp that I used in my example, but fails for the actual, more complicated script that I am using in my real code. But your answer pointed me to my first mistake. I need to use `scriptData = {'script' : "println 'Hello World'"}`instead of `scriptData="script=println 'Hello World'". Also I found out that at least for the script that I use, there seems no encoding to be necessary. I can use it as-is as the value in the dictionary and it works. But I do not know if that would work for arbitrary groovy-scripts or just in my case.