# Post method not available on localhost?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, localhost, httpresponse

I'm trying to implement [this answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17419188/9448090):

```
import requests

requests.post('http://localhost:8888', data={u'post': u'Andr\xe9 T\xe9chin\xe9'})
```

When I run it as-is in my Jupyter notebook I get:

```
<Response [403]>
```

Ok, so access is forbidden. I then try it with my token:

```
requests.post('http://localhost:8888/tree?token=xxx', data={u'post': u'Andr\xe9 T\xe9chin\xe9'})
```

But this time I get:

```
<Response [405]>
```

So the `post` method is not allowed? Why, and how can I change that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, post method is allowed in localhost. Try starting local server and then use post method.

Comment: I think your firewall is blocking the port , turn off your firewall and then try the same....